# GridViewRow Column visible true,false

Tags: asp.net

How can I get a `Product_ID` from a gridviewrow without creating a column because every time I have to make the column visible and invisible to perform gridview data operation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Make it part of one of your columns using a label similar to this:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="name">
    <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="productdIdLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# bind("Product_ID") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
         <asp:Label Visible="true" runat="server" ID="productNameLabel" Text='<%# bind("Product_Name")  %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Hope this helps! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
 <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" Value"<%# Eval("id")%>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="name" visible="False">
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:label id="prodId" runat=server" Text="<%# Eval("id")%>" ></asp:label>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Welcome, and make as a answer which helps you, so its helps to other also.. :)